# PHP: How to retrieve data from mysql and insert to specific user

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert

How would i go about inserting the data below to a specific user only. for example, from the username Ben and his password  "cardboard."

```
 <?php
      // Connects to your Database 
     mysql_connect("blank.blank.ac.uk", "", "") or die(mysql_error()); 
     mysql_select_db("dbBolives") or die(mysql_error()); 
     $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bookings") 
     or die(mysql_error()); 
     Print "<table border cellpadding=3>"; 
     while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
     { 
     Print "<tr>"; 
     Print "<th>id:</th> <td>".$info['id'] . "</td> "; 
     Print "<th>date:</th> <td>".$info['date'] . " </td></tr>"; 
     Print "<th>start:</th> <td>".$info['start'] . "</td> "; 
     Print "<th>name:</th> <td>".$info['name'] . " </td></tr>"; 
     Print "<th>email:</th> <td>".$info['email'] . "</td> "; 
     Print "<th>phone:</th> <td>".$info['phone'] . " </td></tr>"; 
     Print "<th>comments:</th> <td>".$info['comments'] . " </td></tr>"; 
     } 
     Print "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your `name` column, you could use a `WHERE` clause:

```
("SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE name='BOB'")
```

as an example.

Or use a variable:

```
$name = "BOB";
```

then do

```
("SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE name='$name'")
```

Comment: You're welcome. We can now close the question since it has been answered. Just click the White (gray outlined) tick/checkmark till it turns Green near the up/down arrows in my answer, otherwise your question will remain in the unanswered category. @user3447225 This how SO works ;-)